# Aligning a card array in-game

Tags: arrays, user-interface, layout, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a tcg (trading card game) and I would like to know how can I change the layout of the cards while playing. I mean that the cards will be spread in line aligned to the center of the screen both vertically and horizontaly, on a canvas, and when I draw/dismiss a card I would like the cards to fill in the space and align again in game. How can I do that? any ideas? I thought of a solution about when your turn begins (Start from the center of the screen then step back the length of a step X the number of cards / 2 and then spawn the cards one after another), but I can't figure out how to change the alignment of cards when you dismiss one of them without loading them all again...
[Image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypae2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using the same method you used for the initial position you should be able to get the new position. Now you have two positions for each card: `oldPos` and `newPos`.

Your cards are already instantiated. Their positions are stored in `Transform.position`. Your goal is to move from `oldPos` to `newPos`. The simplest way would be:

```
myCard.transform.position = newPos;
```

This will instantly move your cards to their new positions. However, it's not common to teleport your objects because it does not often present good feelings to users. A better solution is to smoothly move the object from a position to another.

To do this, you can move around an existing object by `transform.Translate(new Vector3());`, where the `Vector3` will decide its moving speed. The method `Translate()` is doing `position += movementDirection * movementAmount` as you would've expected.

Moving any object over frames is called `Animation`. There are techniques for animation to make movements look more better (look faster than it really is, or look natural). One common method from mathematics is called linear interpolation, or `lerp`. Using lerp, you can easily compute intermediate points between two end-positions, and it will look natural and nice if you put your objects along the points you calculated. I believe this is what you are looking for.

========

Edit:

Here's an example of how this could be achieved. Note that Card is moving by the same amount of distance per frame in this example. Using lerp (ease-in, ease-out, etc), you could make this animation even better.

Another point I would like you to note is that I'm doing `if (Vector2.Distance(nextPosition, transform.position) < 10)`, not `if(oldPosition.equals(newPosition))`. The reason is that `equals()` is not safe to compare `floats` because they are often stored as `0.4999999` and `0.50001` instead of `0.5` and `0.5`. So the best way of checking `floats` is to test if they are "Close Enough" to each other.

Finally, you could improve the following code may improve in **MANY DIFFERNET WAYS**. For instnace:

1. `Destroy()` and `Instantiate()` is very slow operations and you
   should use `Object Pooling` because you know you will perform these
   operations constantly.
2. The movement of `Card` could be improved by better animation technique like `lerp`.
3. There may be other ways of storing `List<Card> Cards`
4. `OnCardClick()` is using `FindObjectOfType<CardSpawner>().OnCardDeleted(this)` and this requires `Card` to know about `CardSpawner`. This is called `Tight Coupling`, which is known as evil. There are a lot of discussions you can find why this is bad. A recommended solution would be to use `event` (better `UnityEvent` in Unity3d).

CardSpawner.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CardSpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject CardParent;
    [SerializeField] GameObject CardPrefab;
    Vector2 DefaultSpawnPosition = new Vector2(Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 10f);

    List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();

    public void OnClickButton()
    {
        SpawnNewCard();
        AssignNewPositions();
        AnimateCards();
    }

    public void OnCardDeleted(Card removedCard)
    {
        Cards.Remove(removedCard);
        AssignNewPositions();
        AnimateCards();
    }

    void SpawnNewCard()
    {
        GameObject newCard = (GameObject)Instantiate(CardPrefab, DefaultSpawnPosition, new Quaternion(), CardParent.GetComponent<Transform>());
        Cards.Add(newCard.GetComponent<Card>());
    }

    void AssignNewPositions()
    {
        int n = Cards.Count;
        float widthPerCard = 100;
        float widthEmptySpaceBetweenCards = widthPerCard * .2f;
        float totalWidthAllCards = (widthPerCard * n) + (widthEmptySpaceBetweenCards * (n-1));
        float halfWidthAllCards = totalWidthAllCards / 2f;

        float centreX = Screen.width / 2f;
        float leftX = centreX - halfWidthAllCards;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                Cards[i].nextPosition = new Vector2(leftX + widthPerCard / 2f, Screen.height / 2f);
            else 
                Cards[i].nextPosition = new Vector2(leftX + widthPerCard / 2f + ((widthPerCard + widthEmptySpaceBetweenCards) * i), Screen.height / 2f);
        }
    }

    void AnimateCards()
    {
        foreach (Card card in Cards)
            card.StartMoving();
    }
}
```

Card.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Card : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector2 oldPosition;
    public Vector2 nextPosition;
    bool IsMoving;

    void Update () 
    {
        if (IsMoving)
        {
            int steps = 10;
            Vector2 delta = (nextPosition - oldPosition) / steps;
            transform.Translate(delta);

            if (Vector2.Distance(nextPosition, transform.position) < 10)
                IsMoving = false;
        }
    }

    public void StartMoving()
    {
        IsMoving = true;
        oldPosition = transform.position;
    }

    public void OnCardClick()
    {
        UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("AfterDestroy");
        FindObjectOfType<CardSpawner>().OnCardDeleted(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say I got a little confused, can you refrase your answer in a form of psudo code? And what will be the logic of the movement? I mean, let's say I dismiss a card from the middle, how do I apply this logic for every card in order they will move to the "gravitational point" in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I've edited my answer above. Let me know if that works!